# MKAnnotationView's detailCalloutAccessoryView resize needed after content change

Tags: uiview, uikit, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am using the MKAnnotationView's `detailCalloutAccessoryView` property to show a rich view of content. The content could change, whether by user's action on the accessory view or because of changes coming from another part of the app (or cloud), so I want to resize the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` when that happens. I've tried a few things, but none of them force the `detailCalloutAccessoryView` to resize; the only option is to deselect the annotation and then select it again, which is cumbersome for the user if it's a view they are interacting with.

The view that I create myself is added as a subview to `detailCalloutAccessoryView` view, and  uses auto-layout to layout against the `detailCalloutAccessoryView`. It looks fine, but when the content is changed, the inner view is resized correctly, but the outer `detailCalloutAccessoryView` container view isn't.

Here's an example of the view before the change (sized correctly):

[image]

And after removing a couple of tags, the content view I provide is sized correctly, but the callout view isn't

[image]

I've tried this, but it doesn't do anything:

```
- (void) calloutTagsUpdateViewShouldResize {
    
    [self.selectedAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.selectedAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I've also tried to set the frame directly with an arbitrary value, but it doesn't update:

```
UIView *accessoryView = self.selectedAnnotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView;
accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(accessoryView.frame.origin.x, accessoryView.frame.origin.y, accessoryView.frame.size.width, 500);
```

Note: I save the `self.selectedAnnotationView` from the MKMapViewDelegate `didSelectAnnotationView` method.

Is there any way to get the MKAnnotationView's `detailCalloutAccessoryView` to redraw itself, or resize?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this myself.

The only solution I've found is this hack:

```
[self.selectedAnnotationView setSelected:NO animated:NO];
[self.selectedAnnotationView setSelected:YES animated:NO];
```

Note: I've only tested this on a device running iOS 14.8